# Using Manipulate and Module for Riemann Sum

Tags: graphics, manipulate, scoping

I'm trying to write a program using the `Manipulate` function that shows the leftmost, rightmost, and midpoint Riemann sums for a function. I've successfully coded the graphs for each one, however I'm not sure how to apply the `Manipulate` function to it. Here are the graphs I've coded:

```
f[x_] := 3 x^2 + 5
rectangles = 
 Module[{low, high, squarenum, delta, fright, fleft, fmid, curve1}, 
  low = 0; high = 2;
  squarenum = 4;
  delta = (high - low)/squarenum;
  fright = 
   Graphics[{FaceForm[{Opacity[0.7]}], 
     Table[{Hue[0.79, 0.92, 0.88], EdgeForm[Thin], 
   Rectangle[{low + (n - 1)*delta, 0}, {low + n*delta, 
     f[low + n*delta]}]}, {n, 1, squarenum} ]}, ImageSize -> 50]; 
  fleft = Graphics[{FaceForm[{Opacity[0.7]}], 
     Table[{Hue[0.79, 0.92, 0.88], EdgeForm[Thin], 
       Rectangle[{low + n*delta, 0}, {low + (n + 1)*delta, 
         f[low + n*delta]}]}, {n, 1, squarenum} ]}, ImageSize -> 62];
  fmid = Graphics[{FaceForm[{Opacity[0.7]}], 
     Table[{Hue[0.79, 0.92, 0.88], EdgeForm[Thin], 
       Rectangle[{low + (n - 0.5)*delta, 
     0}, {(low) + (n + 0.5)*(delta), f[low + n*delta]}]}, {n, 1, 
   squarenum} ]}, ImageSize -> 56];
  curve1 = 
   Plot[f[x], {x, low, high}, PlotStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 200]; 
  Show[{fright, curve1}] Show[{fleft, curve1}] Show[{fmid, curve1}]]
```

Any help would be appreciated, I've been racking my brain and have been stuck for hours

Comment: It would be really slick to add these controls: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannSum.html, including the estimated and actual integral result - very adaptive little applet with all the methods from drop-downs. The code is on that site, but needs work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way that just plots the specified graph and lets you change the variable `squarenum`.

```
f[x_] := 3 x^2 + 5
plot[squarenum_] := Module[{}, low = 0; high = 2;
   delta = (high - low)/squarenum;
   fright = 
    Graphics[{FaceForm[{Opacity[0.7]}], 
      Table[{Hue[0.79, 0.92, 0.88], EdgeForm[Thin], 
        Rectangle[{low + (n - 1)*delta, 0}, {low + n*delta, 
          f[low + n*delta]}]}, {n, 1, squarenum}]}, ImageSize -> 50];
   fleft = 
    Graphics[{FaceForm[{Opacity[0.7]}], 
      Table[{Hue[0.79, 0.92, 0.88], EdgeForm[Thin], 
        Rectangle[{low + n*delta, 0}, {low + (n + 1)*delta, 
          f[low + n*delta]}]}, {n, 1, squarenum}]}, ImageSize -> 62];
   fmid = 
    Graphics[{FaceForm[{Opacity[0.7]}], 
      Table[{Hue[0.79, 0.92, 0.88], EdgeForm[Thin], 
        Rectangle[{low + (n - 0.5)*delta, 
          0}, {(low) + (n + 0.5)*(delta), f[low + n*delta]}]}, {n, 1, 
        squarenum}]}, ImageSize -> 56];
   curve1 = Plot[f[x], {x, low, high}, PlotStyle -> Thick, ImageSize -> 200];];

Manipulate[plot[squarenum]; 
 Which[menu == "fright", Show[{fright, curve1}], menu == "fleft", 
  Show[{fleft, curve1}], menu == "fmid", Show[{fmid, curve1}]],
       {menu, {"fright", "fleft", "fmid"}}, {{squarenum, 4}, 2, 20}]
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm a step closer with that. I just need to figure out how to manipulate the number of rectangles so that they can increase/decrease based on the user's desire

Comment: Make a function that has number of rectanges as an input and then assign the manipulate to change that number.

Comment: Do you have any guidance on how I could do that? I tried manipulating the delta variable since it contains "squarenum" (number of rectangles) but it wouldn't alter anything

Comment: I've added a second slider to handle the number of rectangles,

Comment: You're a lifesaver, this helped like crazy.

Comment: Got you covered, I don't have a high enough rep for the upvote to be viewable but it was recorded